# Is my div element loading too soon? angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a media player library, ngx-audio-player that I'mn generating a playlist for recursively. If I hardcode the playlist into the declaration, everything works ok, but that's not workable for my purposes.

When I dynamically create the playlist, I get "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

when it tries to get the title of the first song.  **What might be telling is that my console.log of the array doesn't show up before the errors start rolling in.**
I know everything should work as far as types and format because it works when I hardcode it. I thought maybe my html is trying to read the array before it's populated? Maybe someone can recommend a way to confirm that and if so, fix it? Unless my reasoning is wrong.

my html:

```
<div class="container" id="BobDiv">
  <mat-advanced-audio-player [playlist]="msaapPlaylist" [displayTitle]="msaapDisplayTitle"
  [displayPlaylist]="msaapDisplayPlayList" [pageSizeOptions]="msaapPageSizeOptions"
      [displayVolumeControls]="msaapDisplayVolumeControls" [expanded]="true"></mat-advanced-audio-player>
</div>
```

my declaration:   `msaapPlaylist: Track[] = [];`

I'm creating the msaapPlaylist  as part of a series of functions that happen `ngOnInit{}`.

The playlist is determined by the length of the a car trip. so I build it as the trip playlist builds. **note, without the html that builds the media player, everything else loads just fine**

```
ngOnInit() {
...stuff...
}

createPlaylist() {
  this.playList.length = 0;
  this.playListLength = 0;
  this.msaapPlaylist.length = 0;
  let shuffledlist = _.shuffle(this.musicData);
  for (let song of shuffledlist) {
    let left = this.travelTime - this.playListLength;
    if (song.totalSeconds <= left) {
      this.msaapPlaylist.push({title: song.title, link: song.link});
      this.playList.push(song);
      // this.msaapPlaylist.push({title: 'stoofleberg', link: 'assets/music/Ghost Story.mp3', index: 1});
      this.playListLength += song.totalSeconds;
    }

  }
  console.log(this.playList, 'and', this.travelTime, 'and', this.playListLength);
  console.log(this.msaapPlaylist);
}
```

**music data from:**

```
  parseMusic(data: any) {
    const timeRegex = /^(\d+):(\d+)$/;
    for (let song of data) {
      let matchsong = song.length.match(timeRegex);
      let secondsTotal = (parseInt(matchsong[1], 10) * 60) + parseInt(matchsong[2], 10);
      song.totalSeconds = secondsTotal;
    }
    this.musicData = data;
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code of adding data to msaapPlaylist ?

Comment: added that function.

Comment: how are you getting musicData?

Comment: edited again, that function occurs prior to ngOnInit

Comment: plus this:
    let url: string = "assets/musicData.json";
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
      this.parseMusic(data);
      });

after ngOnInit

Comment: should I just post the whole thing? it isn't that much longer at this point

Comment: try to call createPlaylist method inside subscribe

Comment: alas, already am:
      .subscribe((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.distResult = result.route.distance;
        this.timeResult = result.route.formattedTime;
        this.maneuvs = result.route.legs[0].maneuvers;
        this.travelTime = result.route.time;
        this.createPlaylist();
      });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201039/discussion-between-chellappan-and-andrew-steier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are getting data from json file with little delay , so add to check whether you getting data before rendering mat-advanced-audio-player component

**component.ts**

```
isDataLoaded = false;

 this.http.get(url).subscribe( (data: any) => { 
  this.parseMusic(data);
  this.isDataLoaded = true;
 });
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="isDataLoaded" id="BobDiv">
  <mat-advanced-audio-player [playlist]="msaapPlaylist" [displayTitle]="msaapDisplayTitle"
  [displayPlaylist]="msaapDisplayPlayList" [pageSizeOptions]="msaapPageSizeOptions"
      [displayVolumeControls]="msaapDisplayVolumeControls" [expanded]="true"></mat-advanced-audio-player>
</div>
```